# Converting a big.Int to little-endian byte slice

Tags: go, endianness

I have a big.Int and want to convert it to a little-endian byte slice. If I use [Int.Bytes](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Bytes), I get the big-endian byte slice.

Is there any way to get little-endian byte slice for big.Int?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution is to reverse the slice returned from `Bytes()`:

```
b := bigInt.Bytes()
for i := 0; i < len(b)/2; i++ {
    b[i], b[len(b)-i-1] = b[len(b)-i-1], b[i]
}
```

Comment: You can pull out the loop invariant `len(b)-1` from this (call it 'last' or something).